# Extracting sentences from a text document

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

I have a text document from which I'd like to extract the Noun phrases. In the first step I extract sentences and then I do a part of speech (pos) tagging for each sentence and then using the pos I do a chunking. I used StanfordNLP for these task, and this is the code for extracting the sentences.

```
Reader reader = new StringReader(text);
DocumentPreprocessor dp = new DocumentPreprocessor(reader);
```

I think `DocumentPreprocessor` does a pos under the hood in order to extract the sentences. However, I'm doing another pos for extracting the noun phrases in the second phase as well. That is, pos is done twice and because pos is a computationally expensive task, I'm looking for a way to do it only once. Is there any way to do pos only once to extract sentences and noun phrases?

Answer (score 0):

No, [`DocumentPreprocessor`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/DocumentPreprocessor.java) does not run a tagger while it loads the text. (NB, it does have the capability to parse pre-tagged text, i.e. parse tokens in a file like `dog_NN`.)

In short: you aren't doing extra work, so I suppose that's good news!

Comment: So if it doesn't do pos tagging, how it detects a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. Try using nltk (python package)

```
import nltk  
text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")  
nltk.pos_tag(text)  
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```